# HLSL shading distance fade

Tags: xna, hlsl

I have a HLSL code which is not working correctly when I try to add the distance fading.

I've tried this:

```
Output.Color = baseColor*(diffuseLightingFactor + xAmbient * (1 / xDistance));
```

and this:

```
diffuseLightingFactor *= 1 / xDistance;
```

xDistance is the distance between the camera and the model.

can someone please help as I'm new to shaders and don't know very much at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Output.Color = 
    float4(saturate(
        baseColor * ( (diffuseLightingFactor + xAmbient) * (1 / xDistance))
    ).rgb, 1);
```

This ensures that the alpha (transparency) is always 1, and that the other colours are between 0 and 1.  I also added brackets around the sum of lighting factors so that the fog factor is applied to both.